# How to estimate gas manually given the source of a contract?

Tags: gas, ethers.js, gas-estimate

I am using ethers.js to call my own smart contract. I am getting this result:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
```

I also get the above message when I call the estimateGas function using ethers.js so I can't just do that either:

```
     const estimation = await contract.estimateGas.myFunction(x, y, z);
```

So, given that I have the source code of my smart contract, how can I calculate the correct amount of gas to enter?
Other answers I've found online appear to be 4+ years old and I am not sure if they are outdated.

Comment: Usually that means that there's a bug in the function being executed. It generates a revert and the calls fails. Add the contract code to the question, function being called and values used as parameters so we can try reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

During gas estimation it is possible that a transaction would actually fail (and hence has no reasonable estimate of gas requirements) or that the transaction is complex in a way that does not permit a node to estimate the gas requirements, in which case this error is thrown.
In other words, if the contract function is complex, then the gasunits can't be estimated from the node.
Please reference the following link.
[ether doc](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/troubleshooting/errors/#help-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT)